# How to access pod from outside of my cluster in kubernetes? I exposed it as node port service but can't access it with that node port

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I've created a pod for my java application and exposed it as a node-port service.
I'm able to access it using `curl master address:nodeport` only inside the cluster and not from the outside(say my browser).
The purpose of node-port service is to allow external access to pods right? then why can't access it.

kubernetes version v1.13,
Running in the digital ocean cloud.

**Expected output:** masteraddress:nodeport should work externally

output for `kubectl describe svc <svc>`
[image]

Comment: can share your Yaml file config ??? what is coming when you open 192.168.255.229:8081 ???

Comment: @harsh config file of svc or pod?<br>  I'm able to get the desired output when I open 192.168.255.229:8081 or nodeip:nodeport only inside my cluster

Comment: ohhh okay...so with 192.168.255.229:8081  getting output ??? from browser or inside cluster ?

Comment: @HarshManvar only inside the cluster

Comment: you have setup cluster where ? aws digital ocean locally ?

Comment: @HarshManvar digital ocean (p.s: I've mentioned that in my question)

Comment: simply change nodeport type to load balancer digital ocean will make load balancer for you and you will get external IP..use it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188087/discussion-between-aathith-rajendran-and-harsh-manvar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try and locate the worker node's IP address on which your pod is running.
 change `master-address:nodeport` to `workernode-address:nodeport`, it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the node port is serving your application on host: `netstat -tunpl | grep "your node port"` and also with the Local Address as `0.0.0.0`  or your machines' `IP`.

Comment: yeah @vicky I checked and it worked fine using `localaddress:nodeport`, `masterip:nodeport`, and `netstat -tunpl | grep "my node port"` returns my node port

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using NodePort change it to load balancer and access it directly over load balancer Ip address. or eles you can make ingress controller which will make one ingress and you can redirect and exposes services

using ingress and service type load balancer  both way you can you can acess application outside

Comment: from yaml file config also you can change config type:NodePort to LoadBalancer

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure everything is correct and running,Check if port is blocked by firewall rules and open it for external traffic.

Answer (score -1):

It looks from your output like your pod selector is not correct. Your output should be something like

Nodeport: "selector label" 31605/TCP

You have "unset", so this nodeport is not connected to anything.

I have [a nodeport example on my blog](https://beyondthekube.com/identity-management-for-on-prem-clusters/).